# Cannot read objects from active directory with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

We are trying to read some data from our active directory with VBScript and cannot make it work by using another account in the script.

The script will run fine with a domain user which is different from the one in the script but it will fail if we are using the local administrator account.

It looks like the script is not using the account we are providing...

We keep getting this error:

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800A0046.htm

Here's the VBScript:

```html
Const ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_DOMAIN = 1 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772266(v=vs.85).aspx
const ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_SERVER = 2
Const ADS_SERVER_BIND = 512
Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = 1
' Constants required for name translate
Const ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC = 3 ' Catalogue global https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772266(v=vs.85).aspx
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779 = 1 ' Distinguished Name.
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4 = 3 ' NT name


strADUser = "domainuser"
strADPass = "mypassword"


' Get the name of the computer
SET objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strLocalComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName


'Get the NETBIOS name of the domain
SET objSystemInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo") 
strADDomainShortName = objSystemInfo.DomainShortName


'Open LDAP
Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP:")
Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://" & strADDomainShortName & "/rootDSE")
'Obtain fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of nearest domain controller
strFQDN = rootDSE.Get("dnsHostName")

'Open user object via LDAP
set Trans = CreateObject("NameTranslate")

'Specify credentials for NameTranslate to authenticate the domain
'Trans.InitEx ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_DOMAIN, strADDomainShortName, strADUser, strADDomainShortName, strADPass

'Specify credentials for NameTranslate to authenticate the Catalogue global
Trans.InitEx ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC, strADDomainShortName, strADUser, strADDomainShortName, strADPass



' Initialize name translate using global catalog
' -->> http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800A0046.htm
Trans.Init ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC, ""


' Input computer name (NT Format)
Trans.SET ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4, strADDomainShortName & "\" & strLocalComputer & "$"
' Get Distinguished Name.
strComputerDN = Trans.GET(ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779)

strADUPN = strADUser & "@" & strADDomainShortName
adsPath = "LDAP://" & strFQDN & "/" & strComputerDN

Set objComputer = objRoot.OpenDSObject(adsPath, strADUPN, strADPass, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION + ADS_SERVER_BIND)


msgbox "For example show that description : " & objComputer.Description
```

Comment: When I try to run your un-edited script on my 2012 R2 AD domain controller while logged in as a Domain Admin, I get the error:  "Object from with VBscript.vbs, Line: 38, Error: Permission denied, Code: 800A0046, Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error".   When I change just the username and password placeholders in your script to the actual credentials of a Domain Admin, then the script runs but returns only a single one-line message box displaying just this text:  "For example show that description:" and "OK" beneath that.   Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, the script behaves the same way on my side. It will give you the pc description from the AD. It only works if valid credentials are in the script, however it still has to be run as a domain user....